# How to use custom test helper in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

I generated a custom test helper with:

```
ember generate test-helper integration-for
```

Here it is with its code removed:

```
// tests/helpers/integration-for.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Test.registerHelper('integrationFor', function(app, key) {
  return key;
});
```

I can't get it to actually work in a component-test though. I've tried using it directly:

```
// tests/integration/pods/components/itegration-item/component-test.js
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('integration-item', 'Integration | Component | integration item', {
  integration: true
});

test('it renders the google analytics integration', function(assert) {
  this.set('integration', integrationFor('key_here'));
});
```

Which throws a `ReferenceError: integrationFor is not defined` error.

And I've also tried importing it:

```
import integrationFor from '../../../helpers/integration-for';
```

which doesn't seem to be correct based on the [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/testing/test-helpers/#toc_custom-test-helpers).

The docs do not have a corresponding section in the latest versions (>2.4.x), so I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle registering test helpers or if I'm doing this incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things, add helper to tests/.jshintc.
Something like this.

```
{
 "predef": [
  "document",
  "window",
  "location",
  ...
  "shouldHaveElementWithCount",
  "dblclick",
  "addContact",
  "integrationFor"
 ],
 ...
}
```

And you need to import helper file in tests/helpers/start-app.js

```
import integrationFor from "./integration-for";
```

Comment: Tried that based on http://slides.com/jeffreybiles/deck-15#/6 without any luck. Someone in slack group mentioned that these types of helpers are only available in acceptance tests.